# Best way to use Pyothon iterator as dataset in PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, iterator, dataloader, pytorch-dataloader

The PyTorch DataLoader turns datasets into iterables. I already have a generator which yields data samples that I want to use for training and testing. The reason I use a generator is because the total number of samples is too large to store in memory. I would like to load the samples in batches for training.

What is the best way to do this? Can I do it without a custom DataLoader? The PyTorch dataloader doesn't like taking the generator as input. Below is a minimal example of what I want to do, which produces the error "object of type 'generator' has no len()".

```
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader

def example_generator():
    for i in range(10):
        yield i
    

BATCH_SIZE = 3
train_dataloader = DataLoader(example_generator(),
                        batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                        shuffle=False)

print(f"Length of train_dataloader: {len(train_dataloader)} batches of {BATCH_SIZE}")
```

I am trying to take the data from an iterator and take advantage of the functionality of the PyTorch DataLoader. The example I gave is a minimal example of what I would like to achieve, but it produces an error.

Edit: I want to be able to use this function for complex generators in which the **len** is not known in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyTorch's `DataLoader` actually has official support for an [iterable dataset](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/data.html#iterable-style-datasets), but it just has to be an instance of a subclass of `torch.utils.data.IterableDataset`:

> An iterable-style dataset is an instance of a subclass of
> IterableDataset that implements the `__iter__()` protocol, and
> represents an iterable over data samples

So your code would be written as:

```
from torch.utils.data import IterableDataset

class MyIterableDataset(IterableDataset):
    def __init__(self, iterable):
        self.iterable = iterable

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self.iterable)

...

BATCH_SIZE = 3

train_dataloader = DataLoader(MyIterableDataset(example_generator()),
                              batch_size = BATCH_SIZE,
                              shuffle=False)
```